# Can't connect AWS RDS from local Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I can connect AWS RDS using MySQL Workbench but when trying to connect from local spring boot, it says table doesn't exist. Same code working with my local MySQL. 
So not sure what would the problem.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://host:3306/db
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = password-1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

error message:

```
HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Table 'db.student' doesn't exist
Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]
HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m42s281ms410µs591ns).
```

Any idea to for this error. Appreciate you help!

Comment: Kindly provide the `application.properties` file. Remember to change/erase the sensitive data.

Comment: Config looks okay. Can you also provide the log? We would like to see the error probably.

Comment: Updated error message

Comment: do you have student table in your db schema

Comment: If I understand the error log correctly, something is wrong with your code/schema. It obtained connection to the DB.

Comment: Yes, I have connect through workbench and i can see the table and data. Also same schema is working from lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to find out is to use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` this would create a table named `student` in your db based on your current entity class. I am suspecting your `student` table has uppercase in it? Because hibernate implcitly maps your table name, say `@Table(name = "MyTable")`, to `my_table`. Say you have `@Table(name="Student")` and your table in your database is named `Student`. Assuming Hibernate 5, you need to override Hibernate's **ImplicitNamingStrategy** by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`. Or you could provide your own, for reference: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: Yes , i noticed error message all small letters but actual table name all capital letters. Hope thats is the reason having issue. How to make non-case sensitive to access database using hibernate ? or any alternative to use these type of cases. Please advise.

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` adding this to your properties file would override the `ImplicitNamingStrategy` which Spring auto configuration uses by default. Doing so allows `@Table(name = "Student")`  to map to Student table in your actual database.